# Handling Errors coming out of different modules in python

Tags: python, error-handling

I've been playing around with a few libraries and writing programs implementing them in different ways. But the question is how can  I handle errors that come from the imported modules? for example in Ftplib sometimes you get error 500,530,550, and it crashes the program. I tried handling the error in the past with no success, is there any way that I can work around this?
please note that this doesn't just apply to Ftplib but any libraries that may throw there own errors. Ill provide some code for sample from an ftp program I wrote.

```
    def Login(ftp):
        ftpuser = str(input('please enter your username'))
        ftppass = str(input('please enter your password'))
        ftp.login(ftpuser, ftppass)
```

the above script ask's the user for user/pass after establishing a connection to the server, however if you enter incorrect credentials then you would get the following:

```
     raise error_perm(resp)
     ftplib.error_perm: 530 Login incorrect.
```

how would you go about handling something like this? as in the past I tried handling that error by name and it raises another while handling the first one.

Please Advise, Thanks!

Comment: have your tried surrounded the code with `try/except`?

Comment: The program should be showing you an error message. Please include the full output of that error in your question.

Comment: I have in the past, however it raises an additional error while handling the original one, and mark, error 530 listed above is the error.